# Saving data through cursor showing incorrect data while debugging

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have made a simple registration form in which i have called function `insertMember()` with parameters. When i debug this method it shows all the values correct while i put values in `ContentValues()` but when it comes at the end `db.insert(MEMBER, null, values)` it shows password value as email and does not show password field value. Where i am wrong here? Any suggestions please.

```
gender=Male lastname=Ras firstname=Tab contact=021111111 email=123
```

**Code**

```
public void insertMember(String fname,String lname, String email,String password,String contact,String gender)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(M_FNAME, fname);
        values.put(M_LNAME, lname);
        values.put(M_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(M_EMAIL, password);
        values.put(M_CONTACT, contact);
        values.put(M_GENDER, gender);
        long MemberId = db.insert(MEMBER, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = db.query(MEMBER, MEMBER_COLUMNS, M_ID + " = " + MemberId, null, null, null, null);
        boolean success = cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (success) {
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: `values.put(M_EMAIL, password);` is wrong. `M_EMAIL` should probably be `M_PASSWORD` in this line.

Comment: @HannoBinder Silly mistake i must say !! Thanks